# Is there any way to convert the encoding of json files in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have copied the files from remote server to Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity (Binary file copy). Those files are json files and txt files. I would like to change the encoding of the files to UTF-16.

I know its possible to change the encoding while copying the text files from remote server by just mentioning the encoding as UTF-16 in sink side in Copy Activity.I have implemented the copy activity which takes every files as txt file and it was working file. Sometimes, i get some error related to row delimiter and i changed the implementation to binary copy.Now, i would like to change the encoding of those files from UTF-8 to UTF-16. I couldn't find any way to do it.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If a file is stored in blob storage, you cannot directly change it's content-encoding, even if you set the blob property of content-encoding.

The way(via code or manually) to do this is that you should download it -> encode it with UTF-16 -> then upload it again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As i am looking for the automated way, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: @CSK, there is no automated way for this. You should use azure blob sdk to read the blob, then rewrite/encoding by the code.